# Android - Layout doesnt occupy whole screen in 3.1 tab

Tags: android, android-layout

I am testing my application on a 3.1 tab.Inspite of including a fill_parent attribute for one of the layouts it doesnt occupy the whole screen.Is there a particular problem with this Android version?What changes do i hav to make??

Comment: put some code of xml file ; it may help to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// you need to add support screen in android manifest,xml

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                  android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```